# find column name in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Using ipython for interactive manipulation, the autocomplete feature helps expanding columns names quickly.

But given the column object, I'd like to get it's name but I haven't found a simple way to do it. Is there one?

I'm trying to avoid typing the full "ALongVariableName"

```
x = "ALongVariableName"
relevantColumn = df[x]
```

instead I type "df.AL<\Tab>" to get my series. So I have:

```
relevantColumn = df.ALongVariableName #now how can I get x?
```

But that series object doesn't carry its name or index in the dataframe. Did I miss it?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it's unclear your problem, if you have `relevantColumn` this has attribute `name` and `index` does it not?

Comment: what's the actual var name you are looking for? if it has spaces in it, it won't be able to autocomplete. look at `df.columns` to see a full list and check for spaces (including leading/trailing)

Comment: I gave the example of what I would like to avoid typing ( this is for interactive use, in a script I'd just type "ALongVariableName" and be done with it; here I'm trying to make the most of auto complete ). Editing to clarify.

Comment: @EdChum you're actually correct; "name" didn't appear in auto complete for reasons beyond me (I searched for it obviously) so I never pressed enter... Thanks / Sorry !